# Simple plot of longitudinal data in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, longitudinal

I have a simple question but I have spent days trying to figure this out. I have  a long data file with repeated measures as shown below.

```
ID  DEPRESSION  TIME    GENDER
1   5   1   MALE
1   5   2   MALE
1   4   3   MALE
2   3   1   MALE
2   6   2   MALE
2   8   3   MALE
3   2   1   FEMALE
3   2   2   FEMALE
3   2   3   FEMALE
```

I want to plot the trends in depression over time for genders. However all of my attempts have led to each ID having their own line.

I just want one line for MALE and one line for FEMALE.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a ggplot2 solution. Here I am assuming when you say you want the "trend", you want to fit some model to the data. Here I fit a linear model for each gender.

I don't think this graph is that great because it has no indication of how points of the same `ID` are connected. You could handle this in several ways, you could map `shape` to `ID` if you only have a few subjects, or connect them with `geom_path` and map `group` to `ID`.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- read.table(
  text = "
ID  DEPRESSION  TIME    GENDER
1   5   1   MALE
1   5   2   MALE
1   4   3   MALE
2   3   1   MALE
2   6   2   MALE
2   8   3   MALE
3   2   1   FEMALE
3   2   2   FEMALE
3   2   3   FEMALE
  ",
  header = TRUE
)


ggplot(df, aes(x = TIME, y = DEPRESSION, color = GENDER)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)
```

[image]

---

For mean lines, you have to precompute the means per group into a new dataframe. Here I use `dplyr`'s `group_by` and `summarise` for that, giving me `df_summarised`. Then I can use the new dataframe for the `geom_hline` layer only by modifying the `data` argument.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


df <- read.table(
  text = "
ID  DEPRESSION  TIME    GENDER
1   5   1   MALE
1   5   2   MALE
1   4   3   MALE
2   3   1   MALE
2   6   2   MALE
2   8   3   MALE
3   2   1   FEMALE
3   2   2   FEMALE
3   2   3   FEMALE
  ",
  header = TRUE
)


df_summarised <- df %>% 
  group_by(GENDER) %>% 
  summarise(MEAN_DEPRESSION = mean(DEPRESSION))

ggplot(df) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = TIME, y = DEPRESSION, color = GENDER) + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = MEAN_DEPRESSION, color= GENDER), data = df_summarised)
```

[image]

Comment: What if I just wanted to plot the average across ages and not estimate a model

Comment: Updated, use mean instead